# me falla un problema de programacion en c ; A traves de Clion

Tags: c

**No se hacer un ejercicio me he quedado bloqueada , la intencion del ejercicio es que salga esto :**

Elija una opción: 8  ;
Ejercicio 8: cambiar bits  ;
Introduzca un número entero positivo: -1  ;
Introduzca un número entero positivo: 28  ;
Posición del bit inicial a invertir: 3  ;
Número de bits a invertir: 3  ;
El número modificado es: 18  ;  // y como resultado me sale el numero 28 , el que di en su inicio.

**lo que llevo echo es esto :**

````
int cambiarBits (int,int,int);
.
.
.
case 8:
                printf("Ejercicio 8: cambiar bits\n");
                // Llamar a la función "cambiarBits"
                do
                {
                    printf("Introduzca un numero entero positivo:");
                    scanf("%d", &y);
                } while (y < 0);
                if (y < 0)
                   { printf("tiene que ser un numero entero positivo:");}
                else
                   { printf("Posicion del bit a inicial a invertir:");
                scanf("%d", &z);}
                if (y<0)
                    {printf("Numero de bits no valido");}
                else
                    {printf("Numero de bits a invertir:");
                scanf("%d", &w);}
                x = cambiarBits(y,z,w);
                printf("El numero modificado es: %d\n\n", x);
                break;
.
.
.

int cambiarBits(int n , int nPos , int nBit)
{
    int mascara=0, bit=1,resultado;
   
    while (n < nBit)
    {
        bit = 1 << (nPos - n++);
        mascara = mascara | bit;
    }
    resultado = (mascara ^n);
    return resultado;
}```
````

Comment: Date cuenta que todo el código hasta el `break` está fuera de una función. Eso no va a compilar

Comment: Usa llaves por favor. A menos que contenga una sola instrucción no puedes prescindir de ellas.

Comment: A donde te refieres ?? @Mateo

Comment: Por ejemplo la instrucción `scanf("%d", &z)` probablemente quieras que forme parte del else. Pero como el else no tiene llaves y hay una instrucción antes, `scanf("%d", &z)` no forma parte.

Comment: @Mateo , creo que ya estan todos los parentesis , sin embargo el programa sigue devolviendome el numero inicial , creo que es un fallo en la funcion , pero no se donde se encuentra .

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está fallando porque `n` rara vez será menor que la posición de los bits. 28 no es menor que 3. Entonces el ciclo no se ejecuta ni una vez y la máscara queda en 0.

Digo **rara vez** porque el tipo `int` normalmente tiene 32 o 64 bits dependiendo del compilador y el procesador. Así que tomando un entero de 32 bits como ejemplo, son 32 posiciones posibles frente a su rango de valores -2^31 a 2^31 - 1.

Luego **28 xor 0** da 28. Por eso obtienes el mismo número.

---

Otro inconveniente es que aquí se modifica `n`, entonces cuando posteriormente operes sobre él obtendrás un resultado inesperado:

```
bit = 1 << (nPos - n++);
```

Nuevamente se presenta el inconveniente de que el valor de `n` puede ser mayor que el número de bits.

Dicho esto, no tienes que usar `n` para estos propósitos. Es posible que hayas querido escribir `nBit`. Esa es la variable correcta.

---

El código quedaría así:

```
int cambiarBits(int n, int nPos, int nBits)
{
    int mascara = 0;
   
    while (nBits-- > 0)
        mascara |= 1 << (nPos - nBits);
    
    return mascara ^ n;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##bZFhS8MwEIa/51cck0kCi6wKIrTrB3@BP0CELO22g@UqSacfdL@93rWxTjSUpnfvkzfvUW/33g/DFZI/npoWqtQ32N0caqXeOmwAw2vEgPER@6SReqAVyLbl2nwo4LXrIowSwmbsg4Wi5KrewJp3azMoK59lsoCqAixnhe@hfqcXy2axAk1wLZyBGtZmgs5KXXKgl415JoaJARbF2ruwRfcnLT11KX@JZNQUSBrBJe@iA8kqzVF4P@Cx5RACWztmmHN@H/jMI2gx55En5ynq@Iptf4o08y9Ac8zgkLT5CUF8/e1DOdexTdy5HIYHueMn@//6KywV9/8J7JKl8zB8AQ).